# Angularls root directory not found

Tags: neovim, lsp

I have the [angular language server](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service) installed but client doesn't attach when I'm in an angular project because it doesn't have an `angular.json` in the root (since it is an Nx workspace), which (according to the lsp-config documentation) is the `root_pattern` for this language server.

In VSCode the language server is fine, and [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70400214/vscode-intellisense-error-with-nx-angular-intellisense-cant-bind-to-ngif-s) question mentions the "legacy view engine" which seems to be related.

I can't find any useful information about how I can set up the lsp config for neovim that will get it to work without the `angular.json` file present.

I should add I'm using `lsp-zero` to handle the lsp configuration.
I've found scattered bits of info indicating I could use `project.json` as the root_pattern but I'm stumped as to how I can actually do that in the config.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I suppose we would need more information about your problem in order to reproduce it. In particular: What angular language server you have installed? How did you configure `lsp` in Neovim in regard to the angular language server? What is the structure of the project (a simplified structure is better than the real one)?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I've added some more details. As far as I am aware there is only 1 angular language server, the angularls one. If project.json is a viable substitute for angular.json the question then becomes "how do I configure that?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll self answer this question, since I've just stumbled across a post elsewhere that gave me a hint.

I've got the `lspconfig` extension installed and this provides a utility function for the `root_dir` function. Since `project.json` looks like a suitable substitution in Nx workspaces, I've added this to my lsp config:

```
local util = require('lspconfig.util')

lsp.configure('angularls', {
    root_dir = util.root_pattern('angular.json', 'project.json')
})
```

Now when I open a file in my Nx angular workspace, the LSP client is attached and I get all the expected functions. I hope this helps fellow Angular Nx devs who use Neovim!

Answer (score 0):

For me adding '.git' solve all cases, just make sure to git init the project.

```
local util = require('lspconfig.util')

lsp.configure('angularls', {
    root_dir = util.root_pattern('.git')
})
```

Comment: So what happens when you're in a Go project in a git repo? Won't this cause the angular ls to think any git repo is an angular repo?